# Как проследить нажатие конкретной кнопки в Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

Имеется таблица вида

1 | Fod  | foo@bar.com | edit | delete

2 | Bad  | bar@foo.com | edit | delete

edit и delete являются кнопками.
Нужно провести тест на появление алерт сообщения при удалении Bad.

```
all('.button').last.click
```

не запускает алерт сообщение. При этом, если перенаправить его на edit

```
all('.button')[-2].click
```

То страница редактирования отображается без проблем.